# Hyper-V: using git clone with SSH under Ubuntu 18 Guest and MS-Win 10 Host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

Cloning a repository via SSH is not working.
When I try to clone my repository using SSH from Ubuntu guest I got the following error message.

```
john@machine:~$ git clone git@github.com:john/dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'dotfiles'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is the same with `git clone git@bitbucket.org:john/dotfiles.git` and with `git@gitlab.com:john/dotfiles.git`. 
SSH between two linux machine is working fine.

- Guest: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Host: Windows 10 Entreprise 64 bits
- Hyper-V Manager version: 10.0.18362.1

How to fix this error please?

Comment: Does a simple `ping` command (e.g., `ping -c5 github.com` or `ping -c5 8.8.8.8`) work?  If not, your problem is the networking.

Comment: Hi @bk2204, I did the two ping command and both are working fine:
`5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms`.
Using `https` will also work but I need to be able to use git over `ssh`.
I guess I have to configure somethinng in Hyper-V for make it work but I don't known what ...